# Storyboarding with dynamically generated buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am wondering if it is possible to dynamically create segues between views. I am generating all my UI buttons programmatically. Is this possible? I haven't been able to find anything on this topic.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "create segues". But if you mean creating buttons which perform segue on being pushed, you can use `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` on `UIViewController` in respective action. Docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_49).

If you want to transition to view that there is no segue to, I suggest directly calling `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. That is what I meant.